# Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot after converting to ts format

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, forcats

I am getting an "Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot" after converting my dataset to ts format. I am working on a forecasting project and I have this data set which I converted from xts to ts:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(TTR)
library(forecast)

            [,1]
1998-12-31 0.025
1999-12-31 0.038
2000-12-31 0.086
2001-12-31 0.142
2002-12-31 0.190
2003-12-31 0.273
2004-12-31 0.394
2005-12-31 0.406
2006-12-31 0.483
2007-12-31 0.612
2008-12-31 0.746
2009-12-31 0.823
2010-12-31 0.930
2011-12-31 0.987
2012-12-31 1.064
2013-12-31 1.100
2014-12-31 1.160
2015-12-31 1.152
2016-12-31 1.204

#convert to ts
df.ts <- ts(df.xts, start = c(1998,1), end = c(2016,1), frequency = 1)

#select training period
train <- window(df.ts, end = c(2013, 1))

#simple naive forecasting model
fit5 <- train %>%
  snaive(h = h)
```

I am getting the error once I try overlaying my forecast to the original dataset through autoplot:

```
autoplot(df.ts) + autoplot(fit5)
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

I tried changing the start and end values but I still get the same error. Am I missing something here? I'd appreciate if anyone could help me out since I am just starting to work with ts format.

Comment: Just do `autoplot(fit5)`

Comment: Thanks, i figured what was causing the error. 

autoplot(df.ts) + autolayer(fit5) fixed the plotting error.